# All jobs failing in C COMPSs execution

Tags: c++, c, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I have downloaded COMPSs 1.4 and some test programs from http://www.bsc.es/computer-sciences/grid-computing/comp-superscalar/downloads-and-documentation and I am trying to test them. Java executions went fine; however, I amb having problems with C.

I am currently trying to execute the Simple. The Readme states that I only need two commands:

```
buidapp simple

runcompss --lang=c master/simple 1
```

The app builds fine, but when executing with this command, I get the following error:

```
[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Job 1 for running task 1 on worker localhost has failed; resubmitting task to the same worker.

[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: Task 1 execution on worker localhost has failed; rescheduling task execution. (changing worker)

[ERRMGR]  -  WARNING: No task could be scheduled to any of the available resources.
                      This could end up blocking COMPSs. Will check it again in 20 seconds.
                      Possible causes: 
                          -Network problems: non-reachable nodes, sshd service not started, etc.
                          -There isn't any computing resource that fits the defined tasks constraints.
                      If this happens 2 more times, the runtime will shutdown.
```

After 3 checks, the execution ends with no results. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you check the output and error log for job1? To enable the debug mode just run compss with -d flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running an application with the C binding, the default project.xml is not valid because you have to define a project.xml which includes the place where the worker binaries are deployed in each host.

```
<Project>
      <Worker Name="localhost">
        <InstallDir>/opt/COMPSs/Runtime/scripts/system/</InstallDir>
        <WorkingDir>[/path/to/dir/used_as_working_dir]</WorkingDir>
        <AppDir>[/path/to/installation]</AppDir>
        <LimitOfTasks>4</LimitOfTasks>
      </Worker>
</Project>
```